# d3 v4 Positioning labels without touching polygon boundaries

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I'm working on a d3 v4 map that needs short labels positioned within each poloygon generated from topojson.

You can see where I've got to here: 
http://bl.ocks.org/oroojo/9afff90bdb85deb78359a0d5e87a3f31/7606b296a1a47de3b9370d757182386fa35ac650

You'll see that I have the labels centered using path.centroid(d).

This is not ideal as the center is not always the best place to put the label due to random polygon shapes.

I'm sure there is a way of finding a position that does not touch the boundary, though calculation..

Any thoughts?